# explicit solution for Laplace equation on punctured cylinder

Tags: laplace-equation

I need an explicit formula for the rotationally invariant solution of $\Delta u=0$ in cylindrical coordinate $(r,\theta,z)$ for a domain like $D=[0,2]\times [0,2\pi]\times [-2,2] - [0,1]\times [0,2\pi]\times [-1,1]$ (a cylinder from which a smaller cylinder is cut out), with zero boundary conditions on $[0,2]\times [0,2\pi]\times \{-2\}$ and $[0,2]\times [0,2\pi]\times \{2\}$ and $[0,1]\times [0,2\pi]\times \{-1\}$ and $[0,1]\times [0,2\pi]\times \{1\}$ and given boundary conditions $f_1(z)$ on $\{1\}\times [0,2\pi]\times [-1,1]$ and $f_2(z)$ on $\{2\}\times [0,2\pi]\times [-2,2]$.

Separation of variables doesn't work since the domain is not in product form.

Comment: Why the vote to close? Does the person who voted to close know such solution and thinks it is trivial, or knows that it does not exist, and also thinks it is trivial?

Comment: "Analytical" is an unfortunate choice of words, as this is physics speak for what mathematicians would call "closed form" or "explicit" solutions, and (worse) it suggests something else.

Comment: I agree, but this is not a reason to close. I suppose an answer with an integral or a series will be satisfactory. Like the Poisson forumla for the ball.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I wasn't referring to that (and it wasn't me, either); I was just suggesting a cosmetic edit.

Comment: I am convinced that the term "analytical" was not appropriate. I changed the term to "explicit".

Comment: Your problem has no reason to have an closed form solution. It can be written as a sum of other things, but the geometry you describe isn't particularly nice. It is only Lipschitz, with inward corners..